# About Java generics and subclasses

Tags: java, overloading

Okay, I have never used generics heavily and was wondering if I could use them in the following way.

Lets suppose I have this class

```
public class ASuperClass {
    public abstract void doSomething(String arg1, Integer arg2);
}
```

So, if I then extend the above class I would then have the following, where I would be forced to override doSomething with an argument list of String and Integer.

```
public class ASubClass extends ASuperClass{
    @Override
    public void doSomething(String arg1, Integer arg2){
        some code.....
    }
}
```

Now, lets suppose that in my subclass I am fine to override doSomething, but I need an additional String arg in my subclass.  So, what I would like to do is have the below:

```
public class ASubClass extends ASuperClass{
    @Override
    public void doSomething(String arg1, Integer arg2, String arg3){
        some code...
    }
}
```

The above won't compile though because my subclass does not implement the abstract signature defined in the base.  So, to get it to compile, I can of course do this:

```
public class ASubClass extends ASuperClass{
    @Override
    public void doSomething(String arg1, Integer arg2){}

    public void doSomething(String arg1, Integer areg2, String arg3){
        here is my code......
    }
}
```

So, what exactly am I trying to do you are probably asking?  What I am interested in is, is there a way to "force" any subclass of a class, using generics as the arg, to implement a base abstract method regardless of arg list.  So that the following would compile extending the ASuperClass:

```
public class ASubClass extends ASuperClass{
    @Override
    public void doSomething(String arg1, Integer areg2, String arg3){
        here is my code......
    }
}

 public class AnotherSubClass extends ASuperClass{
    @Override
    public void doSomething(String arg1, Integer areg2, String arg3, Integer arg4){
        here is my code......
    }
}
```

So, can you "generic-ize" the base class arg list so the above two classes would compile?  Something like below?  I know the syntax below is wrong, but can you make the arg list generic?

```
public class ASuperClass {
    public abstract void doSomething(<?>);
}
```

Overall, my idea is to enforce consistency in an application where folks are extending some base functionality.  Basically make sure that every sublass of ASuperClass has a doSomething() member function, to ensure consistency (method naming in particular) across subclasses, but it's arg list may be different per subclass.

Hopefully the above is not too confusing.  Interested to know if this is possible.

Comment: That is simply not possible. And generics cannot even come into picture. You have to have 2 different methods in subclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method parameters are a part of the method's "signature", which is used to decide overriding. In order for a subclass to override a method in its base class, to implement an abstract method of its abstract base class, or to implement an interface method, the entire signature, including the parameter types, must match.

If you would like the argument list to take a variable number of parameters, you can use this syntax:

```
public abstract void doSomething(Object ... args);
```

You can override a method with this signature in subclasses, and you can pass as many arguments as you wish. Some unfortunate consequence of this design decision are that

- **Your parameters are now untyped** - each method needs to validate its list of parameters, including their type, before proceeding with the calculations, and
- **Parameters of primitive types need to be wrapped in `Object`s** - primitives need to be boxed, or autoboxed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ASuperClass 
{
    public abstract void doSomething(Object ... args);
}

public class ASubClass extends ASuperClass
{
    @Override
    public void doSomething(Object ... args)
    {
        here is my code......
    }
}
```

This will allow both calls: `doSomething(str1, int1)` and `doSomething(str1, int1, str2, int2);`

Comment: This is what I was thinking of.  So, does this cover any arg type?  For example could I have in a subclass:

    @Override
    public void doSomething(String arg1, Integer arg2, int arg3)
    {
        here is my code......
    }

Meaning, will the elipses Object....args wrapper primitive types?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you define an abstract method like this it means that any object of a type that implements this abstract class is guaranteed to include this method.

For instance look at this code example.

```
List<ASuperClass> list = new ArrayList<ASuperClass>();
list.add(new ASubClass());
list.add(new AnotherSubClass());
```

So we create a list of objects all of type ASuperClass and then add two objects to this list. These objects are of different types but they both share this common parent. This means we can guarantee that they will respond to all of the method signatures on the ASuperClass type.

```
for(ASuperClass obj : list)
{
  obj.doSomething("parm1", 1);
}
```

If you let the subtype determine the parameter list then this would break this. We would know that there was a method called doSomething but it would be useless to us because there would be no way of knowing what the parameters should be.

As others have suggested there is a hacky way of doing this.

```
public abstract void doSomething(Object ... params);
```

Whilst this is strictly true I'm sure nobody in their right mind would suggest actually doing this. Its only been suggested for completeness.

If on the other hand you wanted a variable number of parameters of the same type then you could use it more safely.

```
public abstract void doSomething(String parm1, Integer parm2, String ... params);
```

In this case you will always require a String, an Integer and then a variable number of strings. It's really equivalent to doing this.

```
public abstract void doSomething(String parm1, Integer parm2, String[] params);
```